# Retornar parâmetros de um outro form através do click

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um jogo de poker em C#, mas não estou conseguindo estabelecer uma comunicação entre 2 forms, de modo que o formPrincipal receba valores do formSecundario, utilizando a classe jogador que existe no formPrincipal apenas
Estou chamando o formSecundario enviando o principal como parâmetro(creio que assim podendo acessar a classe)

*Contextualizando: na hora em que o player esta na vez dele e quer aumentar sua aposta eu abro um novo form pedindo para ele que insira o valor que deseja aumentar e se ele confirma que quer enviar mesmo.*

```
frmAumentar aumento = new frmAumentar(this);
aumento.ShowDialog();//Isso no formPrincipal
```

Enquanto no formSecundario estou recebendo assim

```
    public frmAumentar(frmPokerGame principal)
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
    }
```

Porém eu preciso que no evento de click do button1 ele envie os parâmetros de uma textBox que há no form. Mas eu não sei como enviar para o jogador.saldo o valor que ele aumentou.

Answer (score 1):

Parte do frmPrincipal:

```cs
public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
    {
        public Jogador jogador { get; set; }

        public frmPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            jogador = new Jogador();
            jogador.NomeJogador = "Nome do Jogador";
            jogador.Valor = "50.00";
        }

        private void btnAlterarValor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmAumentar aumento = new frmAumentar(this);
            aumento.ShowDialog();

            txtValor.Text = jogador.Valor;
        }

        private void frmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtNome.Text = jogador.NomeJogador;
            txtValor.Text = jogador.Valor;
        }
    }
```

Parte do frmAumentar

```cs
public partial class frmAumentar : Form
    {

        private frmPrincipal _principal { get; set; }
        public frmAumentar(frmPrincipal principal)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _principal = principal;
        }

        private void btnAlterarValor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _principal.jogador.Valor = txtvalor.Text;
        }
    }
```

Classe Jogador

```cs
public class Jogador
    {
        public string NomeJogador { get; set; }
        public string Valor { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado Daniel Gama você me ajudou demais